# python code to play a particular song with reference

Tags: python

There is a file `1.mp3` in the location `/home/<username>/Music/`

Whatever name is given to a value of varible **`a`**, the code should automatically search the specific folder and play that particular (number) song

The code structure

```
import pygame
import time
a=1                                                    # value assignment to <<a>> here
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/prabhat/Music/a.mp3")   # file to be opened
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use string formatting to get `a` in `'a.mp3'` be substituted with the actual value.

You can do it either with

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/prabhat/Music/%s.mp3" % a)
```

or

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/prabhat/Music/{}.mp3".format(a))
```

See [string formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more info.